# How can i set default value to switch button in Androidstudio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I implement  switch button  (not available/ available) in recyclerview, when available is clicked it shows alertdialogbox successfully ,alert dialogbox have 2 edittext and 1 button  but my problem Is when back pressd or when I touch outside of alertbox,the alertbox
closes and  the switch is in available, I need to make that button to not available, how can i do this..

Comment: Show us what you have already tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.